# Pandas: Join dataframes on selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two data frames as following

```
 Data Set A
 ID type   msg 
 1  High   Lets do
 2  Low    whats it 
 3  Medium thats it

 Data Set B 
 ID  Accounttype
 2   Facebook
 3   Linkedin
```

How can I get an updated table with help of join in pandas, it should look like 
 an

```
Updated DatasetA 

ID Account    type  msg
 1            High   Lets do
 2  Facebook  Low    whats it 
 3  Linkedin  Medium thats it
```

I can easily do it in SQL with Update and inner join, how to perform it in pandas, I tried to do it, but most of the operations for append/ merge. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post what you tried as it maybe a simple fix, I think that `A.merge(B, how='left')` should work

Comment: A.update(other, join='inner')

Comment: so does `A.merge(other, how='left')` work?

Comment: No, its not working.. I want that single column

Comment: So, in reality, I have 100 columns in the right table, and I want just 1 column after the merge, just Account, that's again 1 more complexity

Comment: How about `concat([dfA, dfB], axis=1)`?

Comment: @Merlin- The question is correct, I feel, if you have some direct way to perform it than, pls post the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
df4:
    
#      ID    type      msg
#   0   1    High   Letsdo
#   1   2     Low  whatsit
#   2   3  Medium  thatsit
```

```
df3:
    
#      ID Accounttype  xxx
#   0   2    Facebook   24
#   1   3    Linkedin   44
```

```
df4.merge(df3[['ID', 'Accounttype']], how='left').fillna("")
    
#      ID    type      msg Accounttype
#   0   1    High   Letsdo            
#   1   2     Low  whatsit    Facebook
#   2   3  Medium  thatsit    Linkedin
```

Comment: Makes complete Sense, Thanks Merlin

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is no direct way to do it, so following is suggested

```
 a=b.merge(account,how='left',on='ID')
```

create a list of columns you want in final data set

```
 list=['ID','Account','type','msg'] 

 final=a[[col for col in list if col in b.columns]]
```

It will give you only desired columns after the left join