# Joining two Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please, given the two dataframes:

DF1:

```
A       B                    
a1      b1          
a2      b2          
a3      b3
```

DF2:

```
C1      C2   C3  
 0      0     1
```

I would like to do the following DF1+DF2 producing the following:

```
    A       B  C1      C2   C3                  
    a1      b1  0      0     1        
    a2      b2  0      0     1
    a3      b3  0      0     1
```

it is not clear to me how I should use  one of Merge, Join or concatenate. Please, any help would be very appreciated.c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Join dataframes on selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188420/pandas-join-dataframes-on-selected-columns)

Comment: no it is not. It is a complete different case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use some unpacking and forward fill nas:

```
DF1.assign(**DF2).ffill()
```

OR, let's create a dummy key to do a cartesian join, and drop the dummy key.

```
DF1.assign(key=1).merge(DF2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C1   C2   C3
0  a1  b1  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  a2  b2  0.0  0.0  1.0
2  a3  b3  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Do not change the name my friend...please :-)

Comment: Actually Scott Boston Solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`pd.concat` + `ffill`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],1).ffill()
Out[1188]: 
    A   B   C1   C2   C3
0  a1  b1  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  a2  b2  0.0  0.0  1.0
2  a3  b3  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: does not solved the problem. It add NaN values. The solution is provided by Scott Boston above.

Comment: @CarloAllocca .....what is your problem ? So you do not want any NaN during the calculation ?

Comment: Thanks for replying Wen. Yes, the problem was there were some additional NaN values at the first row which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

If `df2` contains only one row we can do it this way:

```
In [30]: df1.assign(**df2.iloc[0].to_dict())
Out[30]:
    A   B  C1  C2  C3
0  a1  b1   0   0   1
1  a2  b2   0   0   1
2  a3  b3   0   0   1
```

Comment: Yeah... I do like that way better it safer with one row.